# Multiple variables in a message box

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox

I'm looking to present multiple variables into a messagebox: ID, Customer Name, Date Added, Venue and Status. At the moment, I can only get the ID to display, the other variables present a Runtime 13 Error. My code is below.

```
Sub LookupTicket()
Dim ibox, tid As Range
Dim dad, sta, ven, cna As Variant

Set Sheet = Worksheets("ControlSheet")

dad = Range("DateAdded_CS").Value
sta = Range("Status_CS").Value
ven = Range("Venue_CS").Value
cna = Range("CustName_CS").Value

ibox = InputBox("Enter Ticket ID:", "Redeem Ticket")
If ibox <> "" Then
Set tid = Sheet.Range("A:A").Find(ibox)
If tid Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Ticket ID not found!", vbCritical, "Redeem Ticket"
Else
'MsgBox "Ticket details for ID: " & tid & vbNewLine & "Date Added: " & dad & vbNewLine & "Customer Name: " & cna & vbNewLine & "Venue: " & ven & vbNewLine & "Status: " & sta, vbInformation, "Lookup Ticket Details"
MsgBox "ID: " & sta, "Lookup Ticket"
End If
End If
```

Thanks guys for any input.

Comment: Is your commented line the one giving you the error, I pasted it into a workbook and it works fine?

Comment: Yes, that's the line generating the error.

Comment: Please try to display *each* variable in its own MsgBox. This should help you identify which one(s) is the source of the error.  Let me know which variables are unable to print to MsgBox.

Comment: Only TicketID is currently working, all the other variables return the error as stated above.

Comment: Type 13 error suggests that the values in those named ranges might evaluate to an error value. Or perhaps those named ranges consist of multiple cells?

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print Range("DateAdded_CS").Address`?  What does it tell you

Comment: Side note: whereas the outcommented code line should work connecting strings (*of course no error values*), `MsgBox "ID: " & sta, "Lookup Ticket"` is missing the **2nd argument**, e.g. `vbInformation` thus generating a type mismatch error 13 here.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `tid` is a Range. You should change that to `tid.Value` if its going to have a single cell.

edit: Check if `tid.count = 1` I get a type mismatch (13) error when trying to value out of a group of cells in a range. Your `Range.Find(ibox)` might be returning more than one value.

Comment: `MsgBox "Ticket: " & tid.Value & ", Station: " & sta.Value`, vbCritical, "Title"

Comment: I think you're on to something. Assuming single-cell range, the `.Value` would not be necessary. Since OP is using the range `.Find` method, I suspect the resolution will involve indexing the named ranges to perform a sort of "lookup" function to retrieve the values for the other variables.

Comment: @DavidZemens when I looked up the documentation on `find` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx), but it says it returns the first _cell_. Color me confused.

Comment: You are correct about the Find method, but from the question it *seems* to me that OP is trying to query some data (in a table or spreadsheet). The code prompts for an ID value and presumably `dad, sta, ven, cna` are column ranges corresponding with the ID field. But unless OP responds to any of the comment/questions, I guess we will never know. :)